# why ng-repeat stop working at level 3

Tags: angularjs

I am using angularjs to render a hierarchical structure. The test case is at http://jsbin.com/agodoj/1/edit

My question is why ng-repeat stop working at level 3 ? Thanks

Here is my model

```
function Test($scope) {
  $scope.cars = {
    chrylser: {
      nameplates: [{
        name: "np1",
        trims: [
          "tirm1", "trim2"
          ]
      }]
    }
  };
}
```

Here is my template

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="Test">
    <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in cars">
        {{key}}
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="np in value.nameplates">{{np.name}}, {{np.trims}}</li>
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="trim in np.trims">
                   (ng-repeat stop working here) {{trim}}
                </li>
            </ul>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just need to move the closing `</li>` tag after your inner `<ul>`. You had the `<li ng-repeat="np in value.nameplates">` immediately closing, ending the loop.

```
  <div ng-app  ng-controller="Test">
    <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in cars">
      {{key}} 
       <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="np in value.nameplates">{{np.name}}, {{np.trims}}
         <ul>
           <li ng-repeat="trim in np.trims">
             works! {{trim}}
           </li>
         </ul>
       </li>
     </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```